# surrounding javascript variable with two double quotes and plus sign jquery $.post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, httprequest

the following code fragment is from an autolookup mechanism,

```
$.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, callback function)
```

inputString is a variable that collects user entered input string and then using the above mechanism posts the data to a php/mysql script and returns requested string data.

My question is an explanation of the double quotes and plus signs surrounding inputString variable. I am confused as to whether the plus signs are there for space characters or concatenation. I understand double quotes are needed as inputString is a variable but why surrounded with another pair of quotes.

Comment: it shouldn't need both pairs, just one pair to ensure the inputString is converted to a String. The plus sign when used on Strings in Javascript is used as a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 2):

Surrounding inputString by a the quotes is sort of type casting it as a string. It is just concatenating it with an empty string. You do not need the quotes. If input string was 5 then ""+inputString would equal "5".

Comment: So if inputString was an INT (5), by concatenating it to "" , it will become STRING ("5") ... Usually , you will only see ""+someVariable. It is quite rare and useless (and even causes overhead) to put the "" on both sides

Answer (score 0):

If inputString is a variable it doesnt need to be surrounded by anything, this should be fine:

```
$.post("rpc.php", {queryString: inputString}, callback function)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
$.post("rpc.php", {queryString: '"'+inputString+'"'}, callback function)
```

Here we are concatenating double quote before and after the variable to make it as string. Here '+' signs are using for concatenation.